# Generalized name for pointers and {l,r}value references?

Tags: c++, types, c++11, standards

Do pointers and {l,r}value references belong to the same group of type decorations that signifies how a type should be accessed? If so, what is the name of this group? For example, `{const, volatile, restrict}` are all *type qualifiers*. I am looking for a name like this that can be applied to pointers and references of all kinds (and one that is hopefully mentioned in the standard somewhere).

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I'm not sure why there would be such a name, considering that pointers do not act similarly to references at all (despite having quite similar uses).

Comment: They are both type modifiers that alter the way in which the underlying type is accessed. Both pointers and references represent some abstraction and level of indirection that one must go through before being able to get the actual value marked using the underlying type.

Comment: References have no indirection. They are as direct as any other variable. You simply have a different accessor-name for the same data, unlike pointers.

Comment: They are part of declarators (ptr-operator) , nothing more is specified

Comment: @user1548637 In concept (and thus with type computations) there is an indirection. E.g. `struct a { using b = int; }; using c = a&; using d = typename c::b` will fail.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "variable declarators". This is not an official term, but a term made from "declarator" and "variable". It includes `*`, `&`, `&&` and `C::*`. I expect that to anyone familiar with the Standards core language text, it should be clear what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ grammar they are both called a *ptr-operator* when they occur in a *ptr-declarator*, as defined in [dcl.decl]/4

```
ptr-operator:
    * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
    & attribute-specifier-seqopt
    && attribute-specifier-seqopt
    nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
```

But that's just the formal name in the grammar, in terms of how you use pointers and references they are not similar and I don't think there's much value in grouping them together. Pointers are objects and can be copied, passed by value, re-assigned etc. whereas references can't do any of those things, they're a completely different language construct.  Trying to group them into something that "signifies how a type should be accessed" is a mistake IMHO.

Comment: I agree that grouping these concepts together may be a bad idea because they do very different things. I just wanted to know what I should name a metafunction that recursively strips all variable declarators from a type. I guess `remove_declarators` is a good name.

Comment: That's a terrible name, _declarator_ is a far more general term in the grammar. `foo(int, char) const` is also a declarator.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the comment. Maybe `remove_attribute_specifiers` would be more appropriate? Not sure what else I would call the metafunction...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the C++ standard doesn’t name the group of “type decorators” that include pointer and reference, but you can refer to them as **type builders**.

Corresponding built in type builders in other languages use different syntax.

The template mechanism in modern C++, combined with C++11 `using`, lets you define custom type builders, and it can be argued that ideally we should now switch over to that instead of the “experiment that failed” C syntax…

E.g.,

```
template< class Pointee >
using Ptr = Pointee*;

template< class Referent >
using Ref = Referent&;

int main()
{
    Ptr<int> p = new int( 42 );
    Ref<int> r = *p;
}
```

However, as of August 2012 this syntax is not yet supported by Visual C++.

Comment: I always use `using` instead of `typedef` after I learned about template aliases in C++11 =) Things become a lot cleaner and more legible, especially when involving function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Something that takes a type and gives you back another type is usually called a *type constructor*. For example, the type constructor `*` takes a type `T` and gives you back another type `pointer to T`.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "constructor" for that, since "constructor" has an established different meaning in C++ (and in OOP in general).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, I didn't invent the term [type constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_constructor) :)

Comment: In C this is called "type derivation", and the C++ committee deviated from C in this regard because that term already has a different meaning for classes. The only point (AFAIK) it has survived is in some text, where C++ says "If T is a derived-declarator-type-list".